# Bit Rate Viewer Alternative

Tags: alternative

I am trying to find software that can monitor bit rate. I would use [Bit Rate Viewer](http://www.winhoros.de/docs/bitrate-viewer/), but it is only for Windows. So is there an alternative available in Ubuntu? I want something that will give a detailed frame-by-frame bit rate data record, like Bit Rate Viewer does. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I asked this question and had since then resolved to just using `ffmpeg -i file` to find it's average bitrate

I have recently come upon this tool called [plotbitrate](https://github.com/zeroepoch/plotbitrate) (which is also quite old now). It does an excellent job of getting me the information I wanted. Marking it as solved.